# Ckeditor can't long press and select text on ionic ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ckeditor5

I use ckeditor in ionic, ckeditor can't long press and select text on ios. when i long press text, ios virtual keybord will dismiss and The system's UIMenuController flashed past。

1. i use the css:

```
{
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

and i can input text on ios,but i can't select text

2. it's work fine on Android
3. it's work fine on ios native WkWebview, but can't work with ionic

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Install it using `npm`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor

```
npm install --save ckeditor
```